# Change background-position on keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**I am new to javascript games.**

I have an idea of game, As an example if I am taking **Solidsnake's character**.

I want character view changes on pressing navigation keys.
If I press left key it should show left view, right key for right view and so on.
How do i get change in image on pressing keys , how can I do this in javascript?
Idea of game-
[image: **Theme i guess-**]

Code in brief-

```
var leftKey,upKey,rightKey,downKey;
    var box = $("#plane"),
        left = 37,
        up = 38,
        right = 39,
        down = 40;



function key(e) {
    console.log(e.keyCode);
    var $key = e.keyCode;

    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == left) 
        leftKey = true;


    if (e.keyCode == up) 
        upKey = true;

    if (e.keyCode == right) 
        rightKey = true;

    if (e.keyCode == down) 
        downKey = true;

    }).keyup(function(e) {
       if (e.keyCode == left) 
        leftKey = false;


    if (e.keyCode == up) 
        upKey = false;

    if (e.keyCode == right) 
       rightKey = false;

    if (e.keyCode == down) 
        downKey = false;

    });



}

$("body").keydown(function(){
   key(event); 
});




setInterval(function() {


    if (upKey) {
        box.css("top", "-=10");
    }
    if (rightKey) {
        box.css("left", "+=10");
    }
    if (downKey) {
        box.css("top", "+=10");
    }
    if (leftKey) {
        box.css("left", "-=10");
    }


},20);
```

Right now i have this code with simple navigation moves.

[Js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stackmanoz/VMM5P/)

Comment: ur moving the image to top, bottom, left and right...try to have 4 different views and where u r changing the css with each keypress change the image accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with CSS to set it right and avoid multiple image requests. You need to have a sprite with all images of the character in a row and then mask with a `div` the area you need to show. Then with javascript you can change the position of the image either by using `marginLeft` or `marginRight` or `left` and `right` (you need to set position `relative` or `absolute` for `left` and `right`).

Answer (score 2):

When you do `e.keyCode == up` and the like, you can change the image source then:

```
if (e.keyCode == up) {
    upKey = true;
    $("#plane").attr('src', 'up-img-src');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Either do this: http://jsfiddle.net/VMM5P/1/

Change the `image src` on keypress:

```
if (upKey) {
    box.attr("src", "http://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/blackblue/128/iChat.png");
}
if (rightKey) {
    box.attr("src", "http://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/blackblue/128/guitar.png");
}
if (downKey) {
    box.attr("src", "http://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/blackblue/128/TextEdit.png");
}
if (leftKey) {
    box.attr("src", "http://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/blackblue/128/preview.png");
}
```

or you can make a sprite and position them accordingly:

*`Suppose box is the div which has a background sprite image`*

```
if (upKey) {
    box.css("background-position", "0px 0px"); // pos 1
}
if (rightKey) {
    box.css("background-position", "120px 0px"); // pos 2
}
if (downKey) {
    box.css("background-position", "240px 0px"); // pos 3
}
if (leftKey) {
    box.css("background-position", "360px 0px"); // pos 4
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to change the attr source for the image.

```
if (leftKey) {
    box.find('img').attr('src', 'ENTER NEW IMAGE URL HERE');
}
```